# Prevent Chrome from reloading a tab on restart/crash

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-tabs

Is it possible to prevent Chrome from reloading a chosen tab (or if that is impossible: all tabs) on restart or crash? For example let's say that I'm browsing reddit.com and I want to shut down Chrome then come back to how the page was when I stopped reading, instead of how it is when I restart.